# How to use jq to create a JSON object

Tags: json, jq

I have the following JSON object:

```json
{
...,
"projects": [
    "abc",
    "xyz"
  ],
...
}
```

And I want it transformed to:

```json
{
  "abc": {
    "name": "abc"
  },
  "xyz": {
    "name": "xyz"
  },
}
```

I'm having trouble creating this. I've tried using `map` as `.projects | map({(.): { "name": (.) }} )` but it's not in the format I want and ends up in an array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for something like this:

```
.projects | map({(.): {name: .}}) | add
```

<sup>[Online demo](https://jqplay.org/s/_K8ncs_OXu7)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

I have a bit of a functional mindset, so I'd reach for [`reduce`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/manual/v1.6/#Reduce) here:

```
reduce .projects[] as $name ({}; . + {($name): {name: $name}})
```

outputs

```json
{
  "abc": {
    "name": "abc"
  },
  "xyz": {
    "name": "xyz"
  }
}
```

Comment: `{($name): {$name}}` does the same thing

Comment: A little less functional  looking but more compact, you could do an assignment too: `.[$name] = {$name}`